# OpengGL unable to draw multiple objects

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I am trying to draw a simple bar graph in C++, using OpenGL.

I was struggling to draw a box... seems like a pretty simple task, but I must have misunderstood something.

So to help me see better what was going on I attempted to draw line loops instead.

For some reason my line loop keeps jumping back to the coordinate (0,0,0). I don't understand why this is the case.

Here is my drawing code:

```
GLfloat* points = new GLfloat[12];
points[0] = 0.5; // x
points[1] = 0.5; // y
points[2] = 0.0; // z
points[3] = 0.6; // x
points[4] = 0.5;
points[5] = 0.0;
points[6] = 0.6;
points[7] = 0.6;
points[8] = 0.0;
points[9] = 0.5;
points[10] = 0.6;
points[11] = 0.0;
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, points);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 12);
```

This works fine for drawing GL_LINES (pair of lines), but does not draw GL_TRIANGLE_FAN or GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP or GL_LINE_LOOP correctly. There is always 1 coordinate at (0,0,0). There are 2 sets of this code, the other with different coordinates. Both shapes have a line which goes to (0,0,0).

I assume I misunderstood something completely?

Probably should mention I am used to the old OpenGL.

Comment: `glVertexAttribPointer` takes 6 arguments, your snippet contains 5...?

Comment: Why are you lying to OpenGL in your `glDrawArrays()` call?  You only have 4 vertices, not 12.

Comment: @genpfault Ah, I thought I misunderstood something, that will probably fix it, thanks.